# Message msg после передачи в другой поток становится NULL

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Занимаюсь разработкой под `android`. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

- Получаю объект `Message`. На месте извлекаю из него `Bundle` и все его содержимое имеет корректные значения.

  ```
  class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          switch (msg.what) {
              case REGISTRATION:
                  countConnect = 0;
                  Bundle data = msg.getData();
                  StartNewThreadForRegistration reg = new StartNewThreadForRegistration();
                  reg.execute(data);
                  break;
              default:
                  super.handleMessage(msg);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- После передаю в новый поток(создавал потоки несколькими способами). Извлекаю из него `Bundle` и все его содержимое равно `null`. С чем это связано? И как с этим бороться?

  ```
  public class StartNewThreadForRegistration extends AsyncTask<Bundle, Void, Void> {

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Bundle... params) {

      handleMessageRegistration(params[0]);
      return null;
  }
  ```

Comment: метод handleMessageRegistration покажите

Comment: Еще до вызова handleMessageRegistration значения уже нулевые.

Comment: Есть ли у Message потокобезопасность?

Answer (score 1):

Вдруг кому пригодится. Решил проблему тем, что выдергиваю из Message необходимые мне данные(Bundle и Messanger = replayTo). Передаю эти данные сеттерами. Однако, так и не разобрался, почему объект Message не возвращает данные. Предположительно, у объектов этого класса реализована потокобезопасность